# Horizontal UIScrollView populated programmatically

Tags: ios

I have an SQLite database table which contains user selected favorite items. I would like to display these items in a horizontal `UIScrollview`, with paging enabled, one item per page that the user can swipe through.

Each item's visual representation on the screen will consist of one `UIImage` and two or three `UILabels`.

I've used `UIScrollview` before but only for 2 pages worth, and the content was all created in IB. Now I would like to create the content (from an `NSMutableArray` perhaps?) programmatically, is there a standard way to go about this?

I could probably go through a for loop of my items and just keep adding to the content size of the `UIScrollview`, but how would I actually draw the content? Will it all have to be created at once or will it appear as the user swipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to add the views as subviews to your scroll view and set the content size accordingly, so it will be scrollable. For example the first view's frame  will be 0,0,300,300, the second view's 0,350,300,300 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make it with 1 UIScrollView and 2 item views. Since you are only showing 1 item per page, you can show item_view_A as the active page (currently visible) and the item_view_B as the next item.

item_view_A ===> item_view_B ===> item_view_A ===> item_view_B.

Update the content of the item_view in the UIScrollView delegate. This way you only need to create 2 set of item view.